# How to dynamically convert any Java object into another?

Tags: types, type-conversion

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to dynamically convert any Java object into another using annotations or XML configurations to define the mappings.

I heard that Apache's `PropertyUtils` provide a way to copy data back and forth between Java objects, and the type conversions are handled by `ConvertUtils` which would require my own customized Converter.

For example:

```
class A { 
  long sellerId;
  long buyerId;
  String orderId;
  Date purchaseDate;

  //getter and setters
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------

class B {
  Integer payerId;  //mapped to buyerId
  Integer payeeId;  //mapped to sellerId
  String externalId //mapped to orderId 
  Calendar tranDate; //mapped to purchase Date

  //getter and setters
}
```

Please let me know if there's an open source component that would provide dynamic Java type conversions using reflections, annotations or XML configurations?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to express in pseudo-code how you would like this library to function?

Comment: Could you give examples of two classes that you would want to convert between?

Answer (score 0):

Why use XML or annotations? May be easier write own function like this:

```
public B convertAtoB (A a)
{
B buf;
B buf = new B(); 
//Conversion routine goes here
buf.sellerId = a.sellerID; 
//etc
return buf;
}
```